# Regex not working, need a good regex for the below rules :

Tags: java, regex, validation

a) The below characters are unacceptable for first name field.

- `*` and `+` values are not accepted.
- Values other than alpha (a-z,A-Z) are not accepted.
- Symbols that are not allowed ~ ! $  % ^ * _ + ` = { }[ ] | \ : “ ; < > ? ( )  & # ,  /
- Allowed symbols are:

  - apostrophe (')
  - hyphen (-)
  - period (.))

b) First name can not have a pattern like " and ". Eg : "John and Miller"

c) First name is a mandatory parameter and it cannot be empty or blank value.

d) One double quote without two characters before the next one is not be allowed and it fails validation.

- Eg : “P”

e) One double quote without a matching one is not allowed and it fails validation.

- Eg : “ABC

Comment: What's your current regex? It would be easier to read if you just listed the valid characters instead of both forbidden and allowed characters. And aren't b) and e) contradictory?

Comment: "[[\\(\\),*+]|[[^(a-zA-Z)]&&[^'-\\.\\s]]]”  - I am not good at regex though.

Comment: What have you tried?  In what way did it fail to work?  In order to post a question you have to at least illustrate a rudimentary understanding of the possible solution.

Comment: You have too many contradictions. For example: "values other than alpha (a-z,A-Z) are not accepted", yet you go on to say: "Allowed symbols are: apostrophe ('), hyphen (-), period (.)". Also, what exactly are you validating? Just a first name input? Full name? Please clean up your requirements to be more clear and direct.

Comment: First Name/Middle Name/Last Name/Preferred Name. Right so can't we exclude those characters and disallow all others ?

Comment: So you're looking for a string that is *required* to be in the following format: `"{FIRST_NAME} {MIDDLE_NAME} {LAST_NAME} {PREFERRED_NAME}"` where the quotes are required to wrap around the entire name and every name is required and separated by whitespace?

Comment: So, this requirement is for all the three names separately. Middle Name is optional, but First Name and Last Name are mandatory. I have three separate fields. So I will be validating them separately with same rules for each of them.

Comment: @tenub: Thanks for the immediate response.You think you can help out ?

Comment: Sorry this pattern [[\\(\\),*+]|[[^(a-zA-Z)]&&[^'-\\.\\s]]] is for unacceptable characters. So I probably need a negation of this I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest I got, hope it helps:

> ^(?!.* and )([a-zA-Z'.-]*("[a-zA-Z'.-]{2,}")*\s*)*$

It can probably be trimmed down though.

Escaped it should be like this:

```
"^(?!.* and )([a-zA-Z'.-]*(\"[a-zA-Z'.-]{2,}\")*\\s*)*$"
```

For JSF :

"^(?!.* and )([a-zA-Z'.-]*("[a-zA-Z'.-]{2,}")*\s*)*$"

Comment: Careful, in the square brackets the `-` is a special character. If you want to use it there you have to place it at the beginning or the end: `[-a-zA-Z'.]` or `[a-zA-Z'.-]`

Comment: You are right, I missed that one, edited the answer now. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Thanks! Can you edit this with escaped chars, because I still get parsing issues :(

Comment: @CodingDuckling:So which is the updated answer the above one or this one ?

Comment: @SandeepAllampalli this one, you can try it out on http://regexpal.com/ by the way.

Comment: Yeah but it complains when I put that inside f:validateRegex , can you update it with escaped charactrers as well ? and does this shout when the field is left empty?

Comment: Now I added it with the escaped characters. It will not shout when the field is empty, but you can check that programmatically probably.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45943/discussion-between-sandeep-allampalli-and-codingduckling)

Comment: The escaped string still doesn't pass.

Answer (score 0):

I would validate with this RegEx: `^(?!.*\band\b)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])"[a-zA-Z '.-]{2,}"$`. It ensures the word "and" is not found in the string and that the string contains at least one letter. The string may also not be less than 2 characters in length and can only contains alphabetic characters, spaces, apostrophes, periods, and hyphens.

Comment: You should escape the period: "\."

Comment: @CodingDuckling, not necessary

Comment: It is showing as parsing error.Probably need to escape? Also for Middle Name is optional, I need to allow it as empty.So Do I need to enclose them in braces ?<f:validateRegex pattern="^"[a-zA-Z'.-]+\"$"></f:validateRegex>

Comment: If you're using it in a code like `function('^"[a-zA-Z'.-]+"$')`, the parsing error happens because you have to escape the `'`: `function('^"[a-zA-Z\'.-]+"$')`. And it's still pretty not clear what the First name, middle name, etc are.

Comment: @tenub:Also Names can have a space, they just can't have an "and" in the middle.

Comment: @Robin:<f:validateRegex pattern="('^"[a-zA-Z\'.-]+"$')"></f:validateRegex> this is giving parsing error too.

Comment: @tenub, why do you say escaping the "." is not necessary? If he does not escape it then the "." will match any character, right?

Comment: If you're using single quotes to begin your string you need to escape the single quotes in the regex. If you use double quotes you need to escape double quotes...

Comment: @CodingDuckling, the `.` character only counts as a wildcard outside of square brackets, inside it's just a dot.

Comment: @Robin: Can you pls post the updated for <f:validateRegex pattern="('^"[a-zA-Z'.-]+"$')"/> without any parsing errors.Help appreciated.I really need it soon :)

Comment: I guess tenub's regex would be `<f:validateRegex pattern="^\"[a-zA-Z'.-]*\"$"/>` (with `*` instead of `+` to catch emptyness). But I'm not sure this is what you want (the field needs to start and end with `"`, no spaces), you should really try to update your question: you have a few fields, what are the exact patterns that you want in each of them. Maybe try to follow a regex tutorial, afterwards you may be able to explain more clearly what you're looking for.

Comment: @tenub you don't match `Ferdinand` (valid name) with that, you may wanna use `(?!.* and )` instead. And I'm not really sure what's the deal with the mandatory double quotes...

Comment: @SandeepAllampalli, I reformatted my regex in my answer, try it out now, mind you it is plain regex so you gotta put it in " and escape those, etc.

Comment: @tenub, I think in this case your regex checks that the string has to start with " and end with " or else it won't validate, but I think having words within " is optional for him.